# Can you make CNContactPickerViewController put "me" at top?

Tags: ios, ios10, contacts-framework, cncontactpicker

I'd like to ask the user to select their own contact info, as a way to fill in a form without making them type it all in.  If I simply do this, from my view controller:

```
import Contacts
import ContactsUI
...
let vc = CNContactPickerViewController()
vc.delegate = self
present(vc, animated: true)
```

It shows a list of contacts and allows the user to select one. That's okay, but I'd prefer a list like the "Contacts" in the phone app, where the "me" contact is at the top, and easily accessible.

Is there any way to make this `CNContactPickerViewController` behave like that?

Comment: I *think* this is possible. I was reading the docs last week, and there was a flag, but looking back now, I can't find it in the official docs (only looked at Swift version).